# Vue JS | create new key + value, in a dynamic builded array ($ajax)

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js, children

What we are trying to accomplish is an calender in Vue.js, the calender gets the values using an $ajax call. After this i would like to manipulate some of the childrens data in vue.js.

I spend 2 hours+ to find a potential method to use this, However i cant seem to find the way to target a property in the dynamic children of the data object.

The last thing i tried is using a '$refs' call, this sorta is doing the thing i need. But i think i cant manipulate the childrens data this way.

My vue object is looking like this at the moment:

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#aankomende-week',
        data: {
            calendar: ''
        },
        methods: {
            deleteAll(){
                app.calendar = '';
            },
            callAJAX() {
                $.post(
                    '/ajax/calendar',
                    '',
                    function (response) {
                        app.calendar = response;
                    },
                    'json'
                );
                console.log(this.$refs);
            }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.callAJAX();
        }

    });
```

And my template is like this:

[image]

And my data array is looking like:

[image]

is there a way i can set a **new** property something like:

```
this.calendar.events.[child].totalTime = this.calender.events.[child].end - this.calender.events.[child].start;

this.calender.events.[index].totalTime = this.calender.events.[index].end - this.calender.events.[index].start;

this.calender.events.[anything].totalTime = this.calender.events.[anything].end - this.calender.events.[anything].start;
```

It would be great to have it in a watcher (So if any values change, it does the building/calculating of the array key again)

Comment: Can you revised your solution expectations?

Comment: Is Vue.set(this.calender, attrName, attrValue) what you are searching? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set

Comment: @Estradiaz well im not sure.. i want to set a value in every child in the array.. so im not sure how i can use the set to target every child and add a key+val to all of them.

Comment: You can use a `map` or `forEach` to achieve this, if the data is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `app.calendar.events` is an array..

```
var app = new Vue({
        el: '#aankomende-week',
        data: {
            calendar: ''
        },
        methods: {
            deleteAll(){
                app.calendar = '';
            },
            callAJAX() {
                $.post(
                    '/ajax/calendar',
                    '',
                    function (response) {
                        app.calendar = response;
                        this.addNewData();
                    },
                    'json'
                );
            },
            addNewData() {
                app.calendar.events.map(function(event) {
                    event.data = 'some value';
                });
            }
        },
        created: function(){
            this.callAJAX();
        }

    });
```

I've added a method call in your response, named `addNewData`. I've added this method in the methods object. It does a `map` on the events array and for each event you can add a certain property. It will return an array with the property added. More info on map [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks! this was it. Awesome i can use this kind of functions together with Vue to change all the data propertys i need

Comment: Remember, Vue is just JavaScript ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code

1.You are setting the value of the ajax response using `app.calendar`, you should use `this.calendar=response`

2.Second you need to use `Vue.set` to add a new property, or insert a value into an array actually. More about this [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats). One note about this, you can't add top level data properties using Vue.set.

Comment: 1. After i set it to this.calendar i can still see the object in my console.. the template doesnt seem to reqonize the values anymore tho.. any idea why?

2. Well.. i need a new value+key in every child... after reading the documentation im still not sure how to do this.

Comment: 1. You're wrong. He hasn't to use "this". Check that he is creating there a function with different context. So the Ajax function could change his context to different one. 2. Vue set is required only on adding and removing properties. The vue is adding polyfil on all array functions. So using array with Vue.set is wrong! He should just call push or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

> `Vue.set( target, key, value )` Arguments:
>
> `{Object | Array}` target

> `{string | number}` key

> `{any}` value

> Returns: the
> set value.
>
> Usage:
>
> Adds a property to a reactive object, ensuring the new property is
> also reactive, so triggers view updates. This must be used to add new
> properties to reactive objects, as Vue cannot detect normal property
> additions (e.g. `this.myObject.newProperty = 'hi'`).
>
> The target object cannot be a Vue instance, or the root data object of
> a Vue instance.

[Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-set)